# Create an array of an array of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, struct

this question is regarding the syntax of an array of array of structs.

I have a struct that takes in two ints:

```
struct point
{
    int x, y;
};
```

I have created another struct that takes in 8 of these structs:

```
//Creating an Array of Array of structs
struct Arraypoint
{
    point variable[8];
};
//Not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
```

Now, in `main`, I want to declare an array variable of type `Arraypoint` with 8 indices, so effectively I will have `8 * 8 = 64` elements of struct `point` and `128` ints (`64` x and `64` y).

Also, how would I access an individual element struct point from the array `Arraypoint`?

Okay after having declared in `main` lets say Arraypoint is 2.

```
Arraypoint arr[2];
```

How do I initialize the elements without having to type in `arr[0].variable[0].x = ...` or without using for loops.
Why can't I do the following, it doesn't seem to work.

```
Arraypoint arr[2] = {  {(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)},
                       {(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)}  }//xy are rand
```

I have used curly braces in my code, the error returned is `missing braces around initializer for type point`  and `too many initializers for type Arraypoint`.

Comment: Might be a good idea to specify which language :) I'm assuming C++ based on the semi-colons at the end of the structs.

Comment: You should know that `(x,y)` is not an object of type `point`. Have you tryed replacing the `()`s with `{}`s, too?

Comment: yup that doesn't seem to work

Comment: This seems like C to me, not C++. In  C++, we don't use arrays any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it: [ideone.com/ix3hC](http://ideone.com/ix3hC). `Arraypoint::variable` has to have it's own `{ }` pair.

```
struct point
{
    int x, y;
};
#define P {0, 0}

struct Arraypoint
{
    point variable[8];
};
#define V { P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P} 
#define AP { V }  //this is the pair you missed

int main() {
    Arraypoint arr[2] = { AP, AP };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++, you'd just write:

```
Arraypoint arr[8];
```

An individual point could then be accessed via:

```
arr[i].variable[j];
```

More practically, though, you'd probably be better off using e.g.

```
std::vector<std::vector<point> >
```

or writing your own class with an overloaded `operator(int i, int j)`. For example:

```
class PointMatrix
{
private:
    std::vector<point> m_points;
public:
    PointMatrix() : m_points(64) {}
    point& operator()(int i, int j) { return m_points[8 * i + j]; }
    const point& operator()(int i, int j) const { return m_points[8 * i + j]; }
};

PointMatrix mat;
m(3, 4).x = 23;
```

Comment: Sure the practicality of the `std::vector` solution depends on his needs for dynamic size in contrast to consecutive storage. But +1 for mentioning it and the custom class solution.

Comment: Thanks :) If fixed-size storage is required, I guess `std::array` might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Arraypoint arraypoints[8];
```

is what you're after, I think. To use them:

```
int firstx = arraypoints[0].variable[0].x;
```

This isn't so pretty though

```
struct point { int x, y; };
struct point[8][8] arraypoints;
```

Is probably better? Don't know what exactly you're after though.

Answer (score 1):

To create an array of `Arraypoints`, you can do:

```
Arraypoint arr[8];
```

To access an element:

```
arr[i]
```

will return the `i`'th Arraypoint element

```
arr[i].variable[j]
```

will return the `j`'th point in the element

```
arr[i].variable[j].x
```

will return the `x` coordinate of that point.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized why I couldn't declare my array as such,

```
Arraypoint arr[2] = {  {(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)},
                   {(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)}  }
                    //xy are randomn integer values
```

its because in my struct declaration of Arraypoint, it takes in 8 elements of type point. So 
I have to create variables of type point to store(x,y) and then i could store this variable in Array point.

```
  point point1 = {x,y}, ...;   

  Arraypoint arr[2] = {  {point1,point2,point3,point4,point5,....}  };
```

Just for anyone in the future who stumbles across the same problem.